# How to model partially crossed fixed effect?

Tags: lme4-nlme, experiment-design, nested-models

in an experiment I manipulated two treatments A and B. A has three levels (A1, A2, A3) and B has three levels (B1, B2, B3). A and B are partially crossed so that there are 5 treatment combination:

A1B1

A2B1, A2B2, A2B3

A3B1

Each subject is exposed to the treatment combination AiBj for once. So there is no random effect to be modeled (I assume). The DV is a numerical variable that measures each subject's performance under this treatment combination.

I am not sure about how to model the partially crossed mixed effect with lmer.

Could someone help? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to handle this would be to treat the situation as 5 different treatments, encoded in a single categorical predictor. With this design you can't get information about `B2` or `B3` separately from `A2`, or information about `A1` and `A3` separately from `B1`, anyway.

You then can use the results of the analysis to get estimates of any specific differences of interest (e.g., `A2B1` vs `A2B2` vs `A2B3` for differences among `B1`, `B2` and `B3` in their combination with `A2` ).

If each of your subjects only got 1 treatment, then you have a simple linear model, to be analyzed by `lm()` for example. If by "[e]ach subject is exposed to the treatment combination AiBj for once" you mean that each subject received all 5 of the treatment combinations but got each one only once, you could include a random effect for the individual subjects in a mixed model with `lmer()`. In the latter case, though, you might want to incorporate the order of receiving the treatments into your model in some way.

Comment: Thanks! I am wondering is there any other "less simple" method so that I can view the two treatments separately instead of collapsing them? Because it's difficult to interpret the treatment of AiBj in our context.

Comment: @AffogatoH not that I see. You never examined an `A` treatment without a `B` treatment, or vice-versa. Also, all of your comparisons among levels of `B` are at `A2`, and all of your comparisons among levels of `A` are at `B1`. So if there are any interactions among levels of `A` and levels of `B` your design can't provide an estimate for them. The best you can do is examine differences among levels of `A` in the context of `B1`, or differences among levels of `B` in the context of `A2`.